# GWT Guice/Gin on the server side problem

Tags: java, gwt, guice, code-injection, gwt-gin

Hi guys with my question. A GWT project, as i have read Gin i usable only on the client side than Guice is usable on the server side. Here is my question.

Let first post some example code.

Server side.

```
public class WebchargeServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet implements WebchargeService
{
@Inject
private Injector injector;
@Inject
private ExecuteOperations executeOperations;

.....
executeOperations.do(); ....
```

Here is the injected class ExecuteOperations

```
@Singleton
public class ExecuteOperations
{
.........
}
```

Also i have servlet module class

```
public class SampleWebGuiceServletConfig extends GuiceServletContextListener
{
@Override
protected Injector getInjector()
{
  return Guice.createInjector(Stage.DEVELOPMENT, new SampleWebModule());
}

} // class
```

.....

```
public class SampleWebModule extends ServletModule
{

    @Override
    protected void configureServlets()
    {
       bind(WebchargeServiceImpl.class);  //is it correct to bind a class like that?
    } // class
```

web.xml

```
  <servlet>
        <servlet-name>.......WebchargeService</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>.....WebchargeServiceImpl</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>.........WebchargeService</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/Webcharge/WebchargeService</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter</filter-class>
      </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>guiceFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>......SampleWebGuiceServletConfig</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

I'm missing something because i get null every time, this code works ok in servlet/jsp env but here... 
Advice place.

Thanks.

Comment: in class WebchargeServiceImpl, the instance executeOperations is null i expect to be init. What do you think ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to map your `WebchargeServiceImpl` servlet in your `SampleWebModule`, *not* in your `web.xml`; otherwise it'll be constructed by your servlet container and not by Guice, so it won't be "injected".

Comment: Thanks Thomas, but i did it but still executeOperations instance is null. I have updated the post ,WebchargeServiceImpl is bind in SampleWebModule. Anything else i m missing?

Comment: Let me reiterate: you have to **map** your servlet (not just *bind* the class) from within the `ServletModule` and **not** from your `web.xml`: `serve("/Webcharge/WebchargeService").with(WebchargeServiceImpl.class)`. See http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/ServletModule#The_Binding_Language

Answer (score 1):

How do your servlets get instantiated? Did you install the [Guice Servlet Filter](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets)?

Comment: Yes i have GuiceFilter declared in my web.xml but .. the problem is still ipen. Thanks Peter for comments my post.