# Gwt + Guice tutorial

Tags: gwt, ioc-container, guice

I'm a Gwt beginner. My remote service implementation now uses a DAO.

For the sake of example, I'm creating it myself:

```
StocksDAO myDao = new StocksDAO();
```

Now I was thinking to add Spring IOC for injecting it.

Then I came across this GUICE framework... it can be interesting but...

How to quick start? Is there a simple tutorial over the web suitable to my simplicity example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

GWT remote service is implemented as a Servlet. To use Guice with Servlets, look at the docs: http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets

Also, this has been discussed earlier: [GWT Guice/Gin on the server side problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6227720/gwt-guice-gin-on-the-server-side-problem)

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the sample application which will demonstrate use of Guice with GWT specifically with Request Factory.

http://code.google.com/p/guice-gwt/

Comment: Link for the sample application is no longer available.